# Storing a character at address location in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

In assembly language, if you have two variables, address a0 and byte t0, it's easy to store t0 at the very beginning of address a0 by typing

```
sb $t0,0($a0)
```

Now, I want to do the same thing in C, and in this case I've got

```
char* a0 = "AbC";
char t0 = 'w';
```

I know I can't access and modify a0[0] directly because that results in a bad access error. What is the most efficient way of replacing the beginning "A" in a0 with the value in t0?

Comment: `sb $t0,0($a0)` - I strongly doubt this will work on the architectures I program. So your premise is wrong already. For the C part I recommend reading the pointer-chapter (and all chapters before it) of a good C book. That is basic stuff.

Comment: Well, I use the MARS simulator and it only fails when the address is out of range (which it isn't if you've defined a label and a value).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot replace the `'A'` because it is in a string literal, which is read-only.

You can, however, store the string in an array, which makes the letters and accessible and then replace the `'A'` easily:

```
char a0[] = "AbC";
char t0 = 'w';

a0[0] = t0;
```

Comment: In C, the brackets have to be after the identifier.

Comment: @DavidCullen Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

`"AbC"` is allocated in read-ony memory. You want it in read/write memory. For that, use

```
char a0[] = "AbC";
```

You now have an array if characters that you can modify (you had a pointer to a read-only string).

Comment: In this way you can also access to a0 with the array notation: a0[0] = t0

Comment: @acornagl, yes, but you can also do that when `a0` is declared as a `char *`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I agree.

Comment: @acornagl, then what is your point?  That you can use array indexing notation with it does not distinguish this declaration of `a0` from the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when using char*a0 = "ABC" statement, a0 is only a pointer which points to a READ-ONLY memory that could not be altered.

However, you can still using char* a0; statement but your code would be more compilcated

> (remember to include string.h library

```
char* a0  ;
char t0 = 'w';
a0= (char *)malloc (10);
strcpy(a0,"ABC"); 

a0[0]=t0;
```